# Is it possible to change the MediaTypeFormatter to JSON for only one class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api, where the global configuration is configured to use:
XmlMediaTypeFormatter

My problem is I wont to extend this web api with a new controller, that uses the JsonMediaTypeFormatter instead.

Is it possible to change the MediaTypeFormatter to JSON for only one API Controller class?

My problem is not returning JSON, I have accumplished this with returning HttpResponseMessage:

```
return new HttpResponseMessage
{
    Content = new ObjectContent<string>("Hello world", new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()),
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
};
```

It's on the request I get the problem. If I have an object with two properties:

```
public class VMRegistrant 
{
    public int MerchantId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller action takes the VMRegistrant as argument:

```
public HttpResponseMessage CreateRegistrant(VMRegistrant registrant)
{
    // Save registrant in db...
}
```

But the problem is when I call the action with JSON it fails.

Comment: Do you include "application/json" in the content-type header?

Comment: Yes and I am sure, just did a another check. Checked with fiddler.

Comment: Not sure this will work, but try using the `[FromBody]` attribute. Not sure it will work if the pipeline is configured only for xml.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have your controller return an `IHttpActionResult` and use the extension method [`HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969014(v=vs.118).aspx) and specify the formatter you want to use:

```
public IHttpActionResult Foo()
{
    var bar = new Bar { Message = "Hello" };
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, bar, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
```

Another possibility is to use the [`ApiController.Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.content(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Http.ApiController.Content<code>1(System.Net.HttpStatusCode,</code>0,System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter,System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue)) method:

```
public IHttpActionResult Foo()
{
    var bar = new Bar { Message = "Hello" };
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, bar, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
```

**Edit:**

One possibility is to read and deserialize the content yourself from the `Request` object via reading from the stream and using a JSON parser such as Json.NET to create the object from JSON:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> FooAsync()
{
      var json = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VMRegistrant>(json);
}
```

Comment: Yes this works like a charm. But my problem is the formatting of the request. I updated my question to take this into account.

Comment: @DNRN See my edit for one possible way of getting the content.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was on a similar track myself :) So it's not possible to use the view model as argument, and somehow force the deserializer to use json.

Comment: @DNRN Not that I'm aware of. If the `JsonFormatter` isn't set in the `Configuration` class, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I solved it using the empty method and deserialzed the content :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to change the `MediaTypeFormatters` for only one class/controller. If you want to save and restore the default formatters you can follow these steps:

- In the beginning of the request save old formatters
- Clear the formatters collection
- Add the desired formatter
- At the end of the request copy back the old formatters

I think this is easily done by an `ActionFilterAttribute`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ChangeFormatterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> oldFormatters;
    private MediaTypeFormatter desiredFormatter;

    public ChangeFormatterAttribute(Type formatterType)
    {
        this.desiredFormatter = Activator.CreateInstance(formatterType) as MediaTypeFormatter;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var formatters = actionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration.Formatters;

        oldFormatters = formatters.ToList();

        formatters.Clear();
        formatters.Add(desiredFormatter);

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var formatters = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration.Formatters;

        formatters.Clear();
        formatters.AddRange(oldFormatters);

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
[ChangeFormatterAttribute(typeof(JsonMediaTypeFormatter))]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "ok";
    }
}

// ...

[ChangeFormatterAttribute(typeof(XmlMediaTypeFormatter))]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. Is it possible to do something similar with the request? I updated my question to include this.

Comment: Not sure this would work with asyncronous request model.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could have your media type formatter only accept the type that is handled by your controller:

```
public class Dog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DogMediaTypeFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof (Dog);
    }
}
```

Probably not the best solution though :I